# rpm: how to disable debuginfo

Tags: rpm, specfile

OS RedHat 8.4

I know that having `%debug_package` macro in a `spec` file will generate debuginfo for a package, and will produce `mypackage-debuginfo-<VERSION>.<ARCH>` rpm. However the funny thing is that spec file I have does not have this macro and yet the debuginfo is built.

However, at the top of the `spec` file there is a few global variables:

```
%global _hardened_build 1
%global sysrepo 0
%undefine _missing_build_ids_terminate_build
%define _unpackaged_files_terminate_build 0
```

I wonder if one of them enables `%debug_package` macro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR: Add the following line to your specfile:

```
%global debug_package %{nil}
```

You didn't mention what OS this is, but my experience is that
debuginfo is generated automatically for binary packages, and you have to **specifically** disable it for non-noarch packages.

How to disable is documented here: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Debuginfo/#_useless_or_incomplete_debuginfo_packages_due_to_other_reasons

> If you wish to disable generation of the useless debuginfo package
> while waiting for improvements to `find-debuginfo.sh` or if it's
> unlikely that it could be enhanced to produce a good debuginfo for
> your package (for example no architecture dependent files, but package
> is not noarch because of the installation paths it uses), use
> `%global debug_package %{nil}` in the specfile, and be sure to add a comment
> next to it explaining why it was done.

And if it doesn't work on your version, you can dig through the output of the following command:

```
rpm --showrc
```

On my Rocky 8.5 version I see that the `debug_package` macro is the one defining the extra package, so setting that to `%{nil}` effectively disables it. You can also see how `noarch` packages have no debuginfo.

```
$ rpm --showrc| sed -ne '/^-13: debug_package/,/^-/p'
-13: debug_package
%ifnarch noarch
%global __debug_package 1
%_debuginfo_template
%{?_debugsource_packages:%_debugsource_template}
%endif
%{nil}
-13: defined    %{expand:%%{?%{1}:1}%%{!?%{1}:0}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped. It was indeed defined in `rpm --showrc` output.